# How to post NULL value from FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular8

I've got the following model (simplified):

```
export interface IClient {
 address?: IClientAddress;
}   

export interface IClientAddress {
 streetAddress?: string;
 coordinates?: string;
}
```

And the following FormGroup:

```
this.clientForm = this.fb.group({
  address: this.fb.group({
    streetAddress: [{ value: '' }],
    coordinates: [{ value: '' }]
  })
});
```

Now when null 'address' field is received from backend, this is being sent back:

```
{ address: {streetAddress: null, coordinates: null} }
```

How can I make FormControl to send this?

```
{ address: null }
```

Comment: did you try { address: {} } or { address: {} as IClientAddress }

Comment: when I wrote "I'm sending", I meant that such request is "produced" by FormControl. Backend validates the model so that either address is null as a whole, or streetAddress and coordinates must be filled.

Comment: I think the cleanest way to do this, is to implement a ControlValueAccessor and add validation to only emit a value if one of your address fields is valid. Add a comment if your stuck than Ill make a stackblitz example

Comment: I fixed it by modifying save funcition - I'm passing customized payload depending on the value of streetAddress. But I will definetly look into ControlValueAccessor. Thank you!